# Resource filtering in modular project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

i have a maven multi-modular project (model,service,util,webapp). I have a few profiles defined in the pom.xml of the webapp project.

```
<profile>
        <id>Dev</id>
        <properties>
            <db.driverClass>..</db.driverClass>
            <db.connectionURL>..</db.connectionURL>
            <db.username>..</db.username>
            <db.password>..</db.password>
            <pathFile>myFolder/myFirstPath/</pathFile>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>Prod</id>
        <properties>
            <db.driverClass>..</db.driverClass>
            <db.connectionURL>..</db.connectionURL>
            <db.username>..</db.username>
            <db.password>..</db.password>
            <pathFile>myFolder/mySecondPath/</pathFile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

I'm trying to change dynamically the property path that is located in my util project.
This is the skeleton of my modular project

```
|-- parent
`-- pom.xml
    |-- model
    |   `-- pom.xml
    |-- util
        |--src
            |--main
                |--resources
                    |--props
                        props.properties
    |   `-- pom.xml
    |-- webapp
    `   -- pom.xml
```

In the pom.xml of the util project i enabled the resource filtering

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

And finally i wrote

> pathToChange=${pathFile}

in the props.properties file. But when i run

> mvn jetty:run -P Dev

the value of pathToChange property doesn't change.
Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are checking the target directory when you look if the property changed or not? And when you say it doesn't change, what value does it have?

Comment: The value remain the same pathToChange=${pathFile}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the profiles in the wrong project. You have them in `webapp`, instead of `util`. These project properties only relate to the project they're defined in, unless this is a parent pom. Properties defined in one pom cannot (otherwise) be used in another pom.